# What happens to the mu-plugins folder when you upgrade to Wordpress 3?

Tags: customization, upgrade, multisite

I am about to press the "upgrade" button in my Wordpress MU 2.8 install.

What is going to happen to the mu-plugins folder?  And is there an equivalent way for me to automatically activate a plugin across all my sites?

Comment: [How to run a test WordpressMu to Wordpress3 update?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/how-to-run-a-test-wordpressmu-to-wordpress3-update); [Wordpress MU 2.9.2 to 3.0.5 changes to category.php](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9062/wordpress-mu-2-9-2-to-3-0-5-changes-to-category-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress 3 uses the mu-plugins folder in exactly the same way as MU used to use it. Everything in there is automatically active sitewide.

Note that WP 3 has some newer methods for dealing with plugins though that you may want to consider switching to. For example, the Network Activation allows you to install a plugin via the normal means and then activate it sitewide and still use the WP upgrade system to keep it up to date. The mu-plugins method doesn't allow that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@jeph perro:**

Nothing will happen to the `mu-plugins` directory; they will just stay there.  You'll need to manually upgrade any of those plugins though.  *(Or were you asking something else?)*